# Turn the list of dictionaries into a single dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I've been trying to convert a list of dictionaries into a single dictionary in such a way where each key is `<city>, <state>` and each value is `<county>`.

In short I have  a list that looks like this.

```
[{'city': 'Normal', 
  'county': 'Madison County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Birmingham', 
  'county': 'Jefferson County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Montgomery', 
  'county': 'Montgomery County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'}]
```

And I would like to change it into something like this

```
{'Normal, Alabama': 'Madison County',
 'Birmingham, Alabama': 'Jefferson County',
 'Montgomery, Alabama': 'Montgomery County'}
```

I tried dictionary comprehensions but can't seem to add two different keys at once.

So I know the code below will give me a dictionary with cities and counties for key value pairs

```
new_dict = {x['city']: x['county']  for x in counties}
```

However, how do I add two different keys? Something like `new_dict = {x['city','state']: x['county']  for x in counties}` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
lst = [{'city': 'Normal',
  'county': 'Madison County',
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Birmingham',
  'county': 'Jefferson County',
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Montgomery',
  'county': 'Montgomery County',
  'state': 'Alabama'}]

output = {f"{dct['city']}, {dct['state']}": dct['county'] for dct in lst}
print(output)
# {'Normal, Alabama': 'Madison County', 'Birmingham, Alabama': 'Jefferson County', 'Montgomery, Alabama': 'Montgomery County'}
```

Here, you combine two keys by using f-string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation to form the key:

```py
data = [{'city': 'Normal', 
  'county': 'Madison County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Birmingham', 
  'county': 'Jefferson County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'},
 {'city': 'Montgomery', 
  'county': 'Montgomery County', 
  'state': 'Alabama'}]
  
new_dict = {x['city'] + ", " + x['state']: x['county']  for x in data}

print(new_dict)
```

This outputs:

```py
{'Normal, Alabama': 'Madison County', 'Birmingham, Alabama': 'Jefferson County', 'Montgomery, Alabama': 'Montgomery County'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a simple for loop?

```
l = [
    {"city": "Normal", "county": "Madison County", "state": "Alabama"},
    {"city": "Birmingham", "county": "Jefferson County", "state": "Alabama"},
    {"city": "Montgomery", "county": "Montgomery County", "state": "Alabama"},
]

result = dict()
for x in l:
    city = x.get("city")
    state = x.get("state")

    key = f"{city}, {state}"
    value = x.get("county")

    result[key] = value

print(result)
```